# Using BeautifulSoup to FindAll HTML Elements

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse this HTML from a site that's cluttered with all kinds of different tags.  Here's a sample of the HTML, with the string 'failed' in the code.

```
<g style="opacity: 1;" class="node enter failed" transform="translate(743.1833267211914,17.941665649414062)" id="return_qtd_validate" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Task_id: return_qtd_validate<br>Run: 2018-11-27T06:00:00<br>Operator: PythonOperator<br>Started: 2018-11-28T06:09:40.070799<br>Ended: 2018-11-28T06:10:10.649864<br>Duration: 30.5791<br>State: failed<br>"><rect rx="5" ry="5" x="-157.625" y="-17.94166660308838" width="315.25" height="35.88333320617676" fill="#fff" style="fill: rgb(255, 242, 242);"></rect><g transform="translate(-147.625,-7.941666603088379)"><text text-anchor="left" style="; fill:#000;"><tspan dy="1em" x="1">return_qtd_validate</tspan></text></g></g>
```

Here is another example, with another 'failed' in the code.

```
<g style="opacity: 1;" class="node enter failed" transform="translate(579.2583389282227,17.941665649414062)" id="update_release_yyyy_mm_dd__jpe4_update_release_yyyy_mm_dd_source_validate" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Task_id: update_release_yyyy_mm_dd__jpe4_update_release_yyyy_mm_dd_source_validate<br>Run: 2019-01-14T18:00:00<br>Operator: PythonOperator<br>Started: 2019-01-15T18:02:17.374226<br>Ended: 2019-01-15T18:02:21.419314<br>Duration: 4.04509<br>State: failed<br>"><rect rx="5" ry="5" x="-314.70001220703125" y="-17.94166660308838" width="629.4000244140625" height="35.88333320617676" fill="#fff" style="fill: rgb(255, 242, 242);"></rect><g transform="translate(-304.70001220703125,-7.941666603088379)"><text text-anchor="left" style="; fill:#000;"><tspan dy="1em" x="1">update_release_yyyy_mm_dd__update_release_yyyy_mm_dd_source_validate</tspan></text></g></g>
```

I'm using BeautifulSoup, and the code below to append a bunch of links to a list.  This part works fine.  I'm getting stuck when I try to search for errors and append all errors (from all the links I'm looping through) to another list.

```
    all_links.append(url)

all_errors = []
for link in all_links:
    wd.get(link)
    errors  = requests.get(link)
    data = errors.text
    pool = bs(data, 'lxml') # where html contains the whole html as string
    for item in pool.findAll('g', attrs={'id' : 'node enter failed'}):
        all_errors.append(item.string)
```

Notice, all ID tags are different.  Maybe something like this would work...

```
for item in pool.findAll('g', 'id' = re.compile(<>'')): 
    all_errors.append(item.string)
```

Basically, I want to find every ID that has `class="node enter failed"` associate with it.

Nothing gets appended to `all_errors` but there definitely should be several strings getting pushed into that list. Maybe the `g` or `id` or `class` is off. I'm not sure exactly where the problem lies.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. If you observe, `class` has attribute `node enter failed` not `id`. `id` has value `return_qtd_validate`. So your code would be:

```
for link in all_links: 
    wd.get(link) 
    errors = requests.get(link) 
    data = errors.text 
    pool = bs(data, 'lxml')
    for item in pool.findAll('g', attrs={'id' : 'return_qdt_validate'}): 
        all_errors.append(item.string)
```

**EDIT:**

According to your updated question and comments, you need to find a static attribute which matches all the errors. In your example, I can see that `class` attribute is static in case of both error examples you've shown. So this code should work (just replace `id` with `class`).

```
for link in all_links: 
    wd.get(link) 
    errors = requests.get(link) 
    data = errors.text 
    pool = bs(data, 'lxml')
    for item in pool.findAll('g', attrs={'class' : 'node enter failed'}): 
        all_errors.append(item.string)
```

Comment: Thanks, but those ID tags will change all the time.  The IDs are relative to the URL that I'm working on.  I have to loop through 1,100 URLs and check the IDs of each, for strings that contain 'error'.

Comment: I noticed you updated the question, check my updated answer.